# Word or phrase for the act of making statements for the purpose of invoking reaction or response?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, phrases, phrase-requests, epithet-requests

It seems to be this passive form of communication. These people will often have the tendency to be quite passive/passive aggressive personality-wise.

For example, this person may walk into a room and say something like *"man, that was terrible"* without explaining the situation until someone asks what, exactly, was terrible. If you don't ask, they may take it further and say something such as, *"hope that doesn't happen again"* and continue to do what seems like baiting for a response.

If no one asks, they often times won't explain at all.

Is there a specific word or concept to describe this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

'Fishing' - If the intent is to start a conversation.

'Provocation' - If the intent is to force a reaction.

Answer (score 1):

**Trolling** would be a contemporary word to consider, even though it would probably imply a more aggressive version of the behavior you describe.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trolling) says:

> to troll: to harass, criticize, or antagonize (someone) especially by
> provocatively disparaging or mocking public statements, postings, or
> acts

Otherwise, I second **provocation** suggested by @KnotWright. Let me add the [M-W definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/provoke):

> to provoke : to stir up purposely